# App works on TestFlight but crashes on Appstore, how do i simulate exact version on Appstore before releasing?

Tags: xcode, debugging, crash, app-store, testflight

I've tested the app in release mode from XCode, TestFlight, real devices ... everything.

And everything works fine.
But my App crashes after download from Appstore.

This is annoying.

I thought the TestFlight version will be the version running on Appstore.
But itsn't, so testing on TestFlight is meaningless?

Anyway to prevent it?, like **simulate exact the app version from store before releasing**?

Crash log from phone. Which will not happen while Testing.

```
Thread 12 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 12 Crashed:
0   *myappname*                 0x0000000102544950 0x1024b4000 + 592208
1   *myappname*                 0x000000010253c718 0x1024b4000 + 558872
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4abfc2c 0x1c4abe000 + 7212
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ac1088 0x1c4abe000 + 12424
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4acfd78 0x1c4abe000 + 73080
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ad0400 0x1c4abe000 + 74752
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c4b26a64 0x1c4b23000 + 14948
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c4b2cc7c 0x1c4b23000 + 40060
```

Comment: Symbolicate your crash log and give the whole log including the crash reason etc.

Comment: @matt I did it, but we only get crash log after upload it to the store, i want to prevent every errors, crash before upload releasing it.

Comment: I'm sure you do. But threading errors, as I said in my answer, are hard to anticipate. if you want help with this particular crash, you must symbolicate your crash log and give the whole log including the crash reason. You might even have to show us the actual code referred to in the log. That's if you want help with the crash. If you don't want help with this crash, but just want to ask about the identity of the builds, well then, I've answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you submitted to the app store the very same build that you tested using TestFlight (and that is what you should do) and if you turned off bitcode when you submitted the app to the app store (which I recommend), they are *absolutely the same executable* and it is impossible that they should behave differently.

If you are catching a bug that you didn't catch earlier, that is probably because you've made a threading mistake. Such mistakes can be difficult to track down because (as your example shows) they do not pop up all the time. But that is not due to the apps being mysteriously different from one another as your question implies.

Comment: Well, i found the error, it's about Spotlight index right after the app has started in background thread. The trouble is the spotlight indexing works on Testflight and only crash on live version. Anyway to test app version with bitcode enabled? If i can have exact live version to run offline before releasing, i'll know why and prevent every errors.